# Text insertion cursor very hard to see over black background

Tags: macos, mouse

The text insertion cursor is very hard to see over black background. Are there any tweaks to make it easier to see?

Answer (score 1):

I use [MouseCape](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20140713153000210). You can find premade "Capes" for your cursor online, or draw your own and save them as png images. It does take some tinkering around if you're a perfectionist, but I made a really beautiful one in [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/) and use it all the time now. Albeit it took me like half an hour to get the size right in MouseCape so...have patience. ;)

Here is the design I currently use: 
[image: Vlad's favorite vertical I-Bar cursor]

This is a copy that I modified to work better on black backgrounds: 
[image]

Here is an example of it on black: 
[image]

Let me know if you'd like me to make you a custom one, like an all white version or white with a thin black outline.

Comment: By default, this will not show in Terminal because it has a custom cursor.  To disable the Terminal cursor so you can use this, use `defaults write com.apple.Terminal UseCustomIBeamCursor -bool NO`